# Rails 4: How to validate and import spreadsheet

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, import, upload

I want to know what is the best way to validate and import spreadsheet using rails 4.

I have a project that has a model `Employee(employeeName, employeeEmail, employeeMobile)`.

I need to validate that data is present and valid while importing or collect the `false` value in one hash and ask the user to correct or delete them.

I want to import all types of spreadsheet. I used Roo but it consume lots of resources. I get lots of errors with rails CSV.

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
def save
    if imported_products.map(&:valid?).all?
      imported_products.each(&:save!)
      true
    else
      imported_products.each_with_index do |product, index|
        product.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
        end
      end
      false
    end
  end
```

This is only brief summary of validating record using roo. RyanB has created how validation works in rails. [validation model](https://github.com/railscasts/396-importing-csv-and-excel/blob/master/store-with-validations/app/models/product_import.rb). You can download the apps in your local computer.

Comment: I heard that Roo consume lots of resources when importing big spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry. I'm coming late to reply. It sounds like you said. When the data file is spreadsheet or excel, it will need a lot of memory and time. I suggest to convert to CSV file to handle it.